# nginx $_GET issues

Tags: php, nginx

When I do a phpinfo() on an nginx server, the `_GET["url"]` value is `/payments/do/accept/1?orderID=123`

This means `isset($_GET['orderID'])` is always FALSE. On a MAMP and AFAIK Aapache server this would be TRUE. Nginx requires an `&` character before the `?` for the `isset()` to be true.

Is this the way nginx works, is it a bug, a misconfiguration?

Comment: This kind off sounds like you're using some form of rewrite rules. Please show them.

Answer (score 3):

you're probably missing the use of [$args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args) or [$query_string](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24query_string);

e.g. you need config like this:

```
....
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
....
```